# Hikari connection Timeout Scala SBT 2.11

Tags: scala, exception, timeout

I am having a little trouble which is driving me crazy.. anyways. We used to have on heroku an scala app 2.11 with java sdk 1.8 and postgresql running smoothly.. but we kinda had to move to azure and since they don't support scala easily as java, node and the others so we had to put up a VM with Linux to run the application. The postgresql database is located on another linux vm which has support from Azure;

The problem is: we are getting this error constantly..

```
! @73fcml3mf - Internal server error, for (POST) [/signIn] ->

play.api.http.HttpErrorHandlerExceptions$$anon$1: Execution exception[[SQLTransientConnectionException: HikariPool-1 - Connection is not available, request timed out after 37892ms.]]
        at play.api.http.HttpErrorHandlerExceptions$.throwableToUsefulException(HttpErrorHandler.scala:280)
        at play.api.http.DefaultHttpErrorHandler.onServerError(HttpErrorHandler.scala:206)
        at play.api.GlobalSettings$class.onError(GlobalSettings.scala:160)
        at play.api.DefaultGlobal$.onError(GlobalSettings.scala:188)
        at play.api.http.GlobalSettingsHttpErrorHandler.onServerError(HttpErrorHandler.scala:98)
        at play.core.server.netty.PlayRequestHandler$$anonfun$2$$anonfun$apply$1.applyOrElse(PlayRequestHandler.scala:100)
        at play.core.server.netty.PlayRequestHandler$$anonfun$2$$anonfun$apply$1.applyOrElse(PlayRequestHandler.scala:99)
        at scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$recoverWith$1.apply(Future.scala:346)
        at scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$recoverWith$1.apply(Future.scala:345)
        at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.run(Promise.scala:32)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLTransientConnectionException: HikariPool-1 - Connection is not available, request timed out after 37892ms.
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createTimeoutException(HikariPool.java:548)
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.getConnection(HikariPool.java:186)
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.getConnection(HikariPool.java:145)
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:83)
        at org.jdbcdslog.DataSourceProxyBase.getConnection(DataSourceProxyBase.java:45)
        at play.api.db.DefaultDatabase.getConnection(Databases.scala:142)
        at play.api.db.DefaultDatabase.withConnection(Databases.scala:152)
        at play.api.db.DefaultDatabase.withConnection(Databases.scala:148)
        at dal.UserRepository.findByLoginInfo(UserRepository.scala:31)
        at controllers.SignInController$$anonfun$submit$1$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(SignInController.scala:79)
```

and it happens not just to this particular requisition but to all post requisitions.. more than the half of the requisitions we have are post. anyways it is really bugging me.. 
on our application.conf, this is our hikari config:

```
play.evolutions {
  # You can disable evolutions for a specific datasource if necessary
  #default.enabled = false
}

## Database Connection Pool
# https://www.playframework.com/documentation/latest/SettingsJDBC
# ~~~~~
# Play doesn't require a JDBC database to run, but you can easily enable one.
#
# libraryDependencies += jdbc
#
play.db {
  # The combination of these two settings results in "db.default" as the
  # default JDBC pool:
  #config = "db"
  #default = "default"

  # Play uses HikariCP as the default connection pool.  You can override
  # settings by changing the prototype:
  prototype {
    # Sets a fixed JDBC connection pool size of 50
    #hikaricp.minimumIdle = 50
    #hikaricp.maximumPoolSize = 50
  }
}

## JDBC Datasource
# https://www.playframework.com/documentation/latest/JavaDatabase
# https://www.playframework.com/documentation/latest/ScalaDatabase
# ~~~~~
# Once JDBC datasource is set up, you can work with several different
# database options:
#
# Slick (Scala preferred option): https://www.playframework.com/documentation/latest/PlaySlick
# JPA (Java preferred option): https://playframework.com/documentation/latest/JavaJPA
# EBean: https://playframework.com/documentation/latest/JavaEbean
# Anorm: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/latest/ScalaAnorm
#
db {
  # You can declare as many datasources as you want.
  # By convention, the default datasource is named `default`

  # https://www.playframework.com/documentation/latest/Developing-with-the-H2-Database
  #default.driver = org.h2.Driver
  #default.url = "jdbc:h2:mem:play"
  #default.username = sa
  #default.password = ""

  default.driver="org.postgresql.Driver"
  default.url="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/cuidarse"
  default.url=${?DATABASE_URL}


  # You can turn on SQL logging for any datasource
  # https://www.playframework.com/documentation/latest/Highlights25#Logging-SQL-statements
  default.logSql=true
  default.logStatements=true
}
```

im sorry if it seems kinda messy but i had to cut some links to post.. After searching and finding absolutely nothing over the web, i tried to change the application server to a w10 and this exceptions decreased considerably but they are still there, catching us when we expect the last

i'll even post a part of our code that makes an sql query.. we started to close all connections but still no good results

```
  def insert(user: User) = DB.withConnection { implicit connection =>
    val ret = SQL("INSERT INTO cs_user(full_name, email, cpf, user_active, mobile_uuid, birthday, phone, access_token, insert_date, modified_date) VALUES({fullName}, {email}, {cpf}, {user_active}, {mobile_uuid}, {birthday}, {phone}, {accessToken}, current_timestamp, current_timestamp)").
      on('fullName -> user.fullName, 'email -> user.email, 'cpf -> user.cpf, 'birthday -> user.birthday, 'phone -> user.phone, 'mobile_uuid -> user.mobileUuid, 'user_active -> user.active, 'accessToken -> user.accessToken).executeInsert(SqlParser.scalar[Long].singleOpt)
    connection.close();
    ret   }
```

when i look to the stack trace i can see that the exceptions starts in SQL method. Any kind of query, select, update, delete..

I also noticed that on the ubuntu postgre vm when i typed ps -aux i can see this:

```
postgres  1668  0.0  0.1 188680  5736 ?        Ss   03:16   0:00 postgres: cuidarse cuidarse-stg MYIP(49711) idle
postgres  1669  0.0  0.1 188572  5544 ?        Ss   03:16   0:00 postgres: cuidarse cuidarse-stg MYIP(49712) idle
postgres  1670  0.0  0.1 188444  4096 ?        Ss   03:16   0:00 postgres: cuidarse cuidarse-stg MYIP(49713) idle
postgres  1671  0.0  0.1 188444  4108 ?        Ss   03:16   0:00 postgres: cuidarse cuidarse-stg MYIP(49714) idle
postgres  1672  0.0  0.1 188444  4108 ?        Ss   03:16   0:00 postgres: cuidarse cuidarse-stg MYIP(49715) idle
postgres  1673  0.0  0.1 188444  4104 ?        Ss   03:16   0:00 postgres: cuidarse cuidarse-stg MYIP(49716) idle
postgres  1674  0.0  0.1 188444  4104 ?        Ss   03:16   0:00 postgres: cuidarse cuidarse-stg MYIP(49717) idle
postgres  1675  0.0  0.1 188444  4100 ?        Ss   03:16   0:00 postgres: cuidarse cuidarse-stg MYIP(49718) idle
postgres  1676  0.0  0.1 188444  4104 ?        Ss   03:16   0:00 postgres: cuidarse cuidarse-stg MYIP(49719) idle
postgres  1677  0.0  0.1 188444  4112 ?        Ss   03:16   0:00 postgres: cuidarse cuidarse-stg MYIP(49720) idle
root      1681  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    03:16   0:00 [kworker/u128:2]
postgres  1832  0.0  0.1 188580  4636 ?        Ss   03:25   0:00 postgres: cuidarse cuidarse-stg MYIP(49738) idle
postgres  1833  0.0  0.1 188444  4108 ?        Ss   03:25   0:00 postgres: cuidarse cuidarse-stg MYIP(49739) idle
postgres  1834  0.0  0.1 188444  4100 ?        Ss   03:25   0:00 postgres: cuidarse cuidarse-stg MYIP(49740) idle
postgres  1835  0.0  0.1 188444  4104 ?        Ss   03:25   0:00 postgres: cuidarse cuidarse-stg MYIP(49741) idle
postgres  1854  0.0  0.1 188448  4112 ?        Ss   03:25   0:00 postgres: cuidarse cuidarse-stg MYIP(49743) idle
postgres  1860  0.0  0.1 188448  4108 ?        Ss   03:26   0:00 postgres: cuidarse cuidarse-stg MYIP(49752) idle
postgres  1861  0.0  0.1 188448  4100 ?        Ss   03:26   0:00 postgres: cuidarse cuidarse-stg MYIP(49753) idle
postgres  1870  0.0  0.1 188448  4108 ?        Ss   03:26   0:00 postgres: cuidarse cuidarse-stg MYIP(49757) idle
postgres  1871  0.0  0.1 188448  4108 ?        Ss   03:26   0:00 postgres: cuidarse cuidarse-stg MYIP(49758) idle
postgres  1877  0.0  0.1 188448  4112 ?        Ss   03:27   0:00 postgres: cuidarse cuidarse-stg MYIP(49759) idle
```

i dont know for sure what it means but i think that there are too much idle connections open with the DB. I sometimes kill all of theses but makes no much of difference.

well i think i have posted everything here.. and really hope that anyone can help me.. please :D

I am sorry for my terrible english.. if i was not clear with something please tell me.. good night and thanks already